# How do I check a directory for a file name given by an InputBox in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

My code asks the user to input a file name. We'll say we have 5 text files in directory "C:\Users\aUser\Desktop\myFolder". These text files are named A, B, C, D, and E.

If the text file exists, then I would like to write over the contents with a script I've already made. If the text file does not exist, I would like to make one with the file name they inputted, and populate it [with the script I've already written].

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `Dir("C:\Users\aUser\Desktop\myFolder\" & fName)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you explain it, it seems that the easiest workflow would be:

1) Delete the file if exists

```
Sub test()

Dim FSO As FileSystemObject

Dim sPath As String

sPath = "U:\Test.txt"

Set FSO = New FileSystemObject
If FSO.FileExists(sPath) Then
    FSO.DeleteFile (sPath)
End If

End Sub
```

Copy the script (I assume also a txt file) into the path: 
FileCopy "U:\Script", sPath

If you have the script in a string variable:

```
Set txtFile = FSO.CreateTextFile(sPath, True)
txtFile.WriteLine(sText)
FSO.Close
End Sub
```

If the script is contained in an array, you can loop through the array and produce multiple writelines.
Don't forget to reference the Microsoft Scripting Runtime library.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

- locates the folder for the logged on user regardless of OS
- checks that the user input file is contained in a master list (held by `StrFiles`)
- then either creates a new file if it doesn't exist, or
- provides a logic branch for you to add your overrwrite script

  Sub

**code**

```
GetFiles()
Dim wsShell As Object
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFil As Object
Dim strFolder As String
Dim StrFile As String
Dim StrFiles()
StrFiles = Array("A.txt", "B.txt", "C.txt")
Set wsShell = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
strFolder = wsShell.specialFolders("Desktop") & "\myFolder"
StrFile = Application.InputBox("Please enter A.txt, B.txt", "File Selection", , , , , 2)
If IsError(Application.Match(StrFile, StrFiles, 0)) Then
MsgBox StrFile & " is invalid", vbCritical
Exit Sub
End If
If Len(Dir(strFolder & "\" & StrFile)) = 0 Then
'make file
Set objFSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
Set objFil = objFSO.createtextfile(strFolder & "\" & StrFile, 2)
objFil.Close
Else
'write over file
'add your code here
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. Not sure if this would work though. I can't store the names of the files in the array, because in a production environment I won't know the names of any of the files [they're names of clients]. So, I would need the script to bump the given name against all the names of the text files [which could be any name really].

Comment: This is over thinking it a bit.  Just call `CreateTextFile` with the file path and name (may want to verify the _folder_ exists) and the second parameter of `True`.  This will create the file if it doesn't exist, or overwrite it if it does.

Comment: @STANGMMX Then you can delete the array part  :)                                                           Chrisneilsen, the OP asked for a conditional check as to whether it existed, while the script to be run may be identical its a little sloppy to take short-cuts just because it *might* be okay.